# Embed camera frame in web app html5

Tags: html, camera

I want to beuild web app that the user will upload a image from device camera.
I know that I can use `<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">`.

My question is that if there is a way to "embed" the camera screen in the page itself. In other words, I want that the screen will look like this:

[image: Mockup]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you can read the article [Capturing Audio & Video in HTML5](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/).

Here is the code to access your camera:

```
<video autoplay></video>

<script>
  var errorCallback = function(e) {
    console.log('Reeeejected!', e);
  };

  // Not showing vendor prefixes.
  navigator.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: true}, function(localMediaStream) {
    var video = document.querySelector('video');
    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(localMediaStream);

    // Note: onloadedmetadata doesn't fire in Chrome when using it with getUserMedia.
    // See crbug.com/110938.
    video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
      // Ready to go. Do some stuff.
    };
  }, errorCallback);
</script>
```

Taking screenshots:

```
<video autoplay></video>
<img src="">
<canvas style="display:none;"></canvas>

<script>
  var video = document.querySelector('video');
  var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var localMediaStream = null;

  function snapshot() {
    if (localMediaStream) {
      ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0);
      // "image/webp" works in Chrome.
      // Other browsers will fall back to image/png.
      document.querySelector('img').src = canvas.toDataURL('image/webp');
    }
  }

  video.addEventListener('click', snapshot, false);

  // Not showing vendor prefixes or code that works cross-browser.
  navigator.getUserMedia({video: true}, function(stream) {
    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
    localMediaStream = stream;
  }, errorCallback);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Video tag is there HTML5 to handle this. and you need to use getUserMedia api to handle the streaming. most of the modern browsers supports it. To validate whether it is supported, use javascript to check that. You can try this:

```
if(navigator.getUserMedia()) ....
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good tutorial on how to use a web cam to capture images. The same person also has a tutorial on capturing video to GIFs.
http://davidwalsh.name/browser-camera
[HTML 5 Image capture tutorial & demo](http://davidwalsh.name/browser-camera)